# Is it possible to capture images using Intent in Camera2 api's

Tags: android-camera

I am on Android L which is using Camera2 api's.I want to write a Camera app for Image capture using Intent using Camera2 api's.Is it possible.If yes could you share a sample code for it

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#basics) tries to be clear:

> The Android framework supports capturing images and video through the android.hardware.camera2 API or camera Intent.

The Intent has not changed when the old camera API got deprecated.